# How to use ～に同意する to agree or disagree with a person?

Tags: word-choice, words, expressions

A couple of times I've tried to say "I agree with..." or "he agrees with..." but I don't know whether I'm using `同意{どうい}する` correctly.

In what ways should `に同意{どうい}している` be used? Also, which particles should be used? Can only `に` be used before `同意{どうい}する` or are there circumstances where other particles are used as well, such as `と` and `を`?

In many examples I've found using `同意{どうい}する`, I've seen `（だ）ということに` or just `（な）ことに` (the `だ`/`な` after na adjectives/nouns and without `だ`/`な` after i adjectives/verbs it seems.) Is there a specific reason for using one over the other, e.g. is the longer `（だ）ということに` more polite, and what do these mean?

Some example sentences:

- I agree with his opinion:

  > `彼{かれ}の意見{いけん}に同意{どうい}します。`
- I agree with him that oranges are tasty:

  > `オレンジはおいしいということ彼{かれ}に同意{どうい}します。`
- He agrees that apples are tasty:

  > `彼{かれ}はりんごがおいしいことに同意{どうい}します。`
- Many people agree that brussel sprouts don't taste nice:

  > `芽{め}キャベツはおいしくないということに同意{どうい}する人{ひと}が多{おお}い。`

**See also:** [What are the different ways of saying to agree or disagree with a person?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3522/) for other ways of agreeing/disagreeing with someone.

Comment: I think 賛成 has the added meaning of "approve"

Comment: I think a common one is `同感【どうかん】`.  It seems to be a little "softer" and more familiar than `同意【どうい】`.

Comment: The example `オレンジはおいしいだということに彼に同意します` is totally ungrammatical. `芽キャベツはおいしくないだということに同意する人が多い` is ungrammatical unless you are referring to some non-standard dialect.

Comment: @sawa: Can you give any suggestions on how to fix it please? I used the sentence `自然{しぜん}の保護{ほご}は土地開発{とちかいはつ}よりはるかに重要{じゅうよう}だということに同意{どうい}する人{ひと}が多{おお}い。` (Many people agree that protecting nature is much more important than developing land.) as a reference.

Comment: For `オレンジ...`, you cannot have two `...に` phrases. Remove either. And for the two sentences that I mentioned, remove `だと`.

Comment: @sawa: remove とか or replace it with と to make `おいしいということ`? (`おいしいいうこと` doesn't get any google results.) I've edited it to say `おいしいということ`, but if there's still problems, I'll let anyone edit it (I would make this community wiki but there's no button for it :P)

Comment: @DavidMorrissey Your editing is right. I should have said to remove `だ`. Sorry.

Comment: 「オレンジはおいしい**ということ彼**に同意します。」 is incorrect. 「ということ+彼」はダメです

Answer (score 3):

You can find a lot of examples [here](http://eow.alc.co.jp/%E5%90%8C%E6%84%8F/UTF-8/?pg=1) (you may want to check later pages), which will explain a lot.

It seems that we do use "に" for "同意する".

"ということ" literally means "the so-called", which I think is a little more polite.

Also to @sawa, search in the above site with "[いという](http://eow.alc.co.jp/%E3%81%84%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86/UTF-8/)" and "[いだという](http://eow.alc.co.jp/%E3%81%84%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86/UTF-8/)" (I know they are not words nor phrases ...) gives interesting results. It seems that wile i adjectives, "美味しいだということ" can be used.

And I think "オレンジはおいしいということ彼に同意します" is still a little weird, maybe it should be "オレンジ**が**おいしいだということ**について**彼に同意します。". A phrase with nothing in the end doesn't sound natural. (About "は" and "が", I just feel this way, I am not able to explain it in details.)

BTW, I am not native, so correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: 「おいしい**だ**ということ」 is ungrammatical. Should be 「おいしいということ」.

Comment: `"いだという" ... gives interesting results` <- 「形容詞+だという」の例はありませんが。。